# Complicated array loop output

Tags: php, arrays, loops

This is a difficult question to explain so bear with me...

I need to output a form wizard based on the following array:

```
Array
(
[about_you] => Array
    (
        [qb-name] => about_you
        [qb-label] => About You
        [qb-type] => ttl
    )

[your_name] => Array
    (
        [qb-name] => your_name
        [qb-label] => What is your name?
        [required] => required
        [qb-type] => slt
    )

[website] => Array
    (
        [qb-name] => website
        [qb-label] => What is your current website?
        [required] => 
        [qb-type] => slt
    )

[your_requirements] => Array
    (
        [qb-name] => your_requirements
        [qb-label] => Your Requirements
        [qb-type] => ttl
    )

[hosting] => Array
    (
        [qb-name] => age
        [qb-label] => How old are you?
        [sq-option] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0-20
                [1] => 21-40
                [2] => 40+
            )

        [qb-type] => sel
    )

[likes] => Array
    (
        [qb-name] => likes
        [qb-label] => What do you like?
        [required] => required
        [qb-type] => mlt
    )

)
```

The `qb-type => ttl` field is a title field and also a new page in the form wizard the output would be as follows for each title:

```
<div id="wizard">
    <!-- foreach.... -->
    <h1> [qb-label] </h1>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <!-- /foreach -->
</div>
```

so the output from the above array would be...

```html
<div id="wizard">
      <h1>About You</h1>
      <div class="content"></div>

      <h1>Your Requirements</h1>
      <div class="content"></div>
   </div>
```

My question is how can I display anything below the title field in the `.content` area for example:

```html
<div id="wizard">
          <h1>About You</h1>
          <div class="content">
            <p>
              <label>What is your name?</label>
              <input name="your_name" />
             </p>
            <p>
              <label>What is your current website?</label>
              <input name="your_name" />
             </p>
          </div>

          <h1>Your Requirements</h1>
          <div class="content">
             How old are you?
             What do you like?
          </div>
       </div>
```

I've managed to out put the title but I'm not sure how I can add the sub fields to each section:

```
<div id="wizard">
<?php foreach($form as $field=>$option): ?>
    <?php if($option['qb-type'] == 'ttl'): ?>
        <h1><?= $option['qb-label'] ?></h1>
        <div>The content goes here</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I hope I've managed to explain everything well enough, but please feel free to ask if you need a better explanation.

**EDIT** Any data directly below the title until you reach the next title would be considered part of the ttl section

Comment: I do not understand where the data to be displayed are when the qb-type is equal to "ttl". You do not provided any or any way to understand where which array elements are to be considered part of the ttl member

Comment: Sorry @RiccardoC, I don't understand your question, could you explain?

Comment: Any data directly below the title until you reach the next title would be considered part of the ttl section

Comment: Undestood... I thnk it's not a good design, but I'll think about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?php $first = true; ?>
<?php foreach( $form as $field=>$options ) { ?>
    <?php if( $options[ "qb-type" ] == "ttl" ) { ?>
        <?php if( !$first ) echo "</div>";?>
        <?php $first = false; ?>
        <h1><?= $options['qb-label'] ?></h1><div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <p>
            <label><?= $options["qb-label"]?></label>
            <input type="text" name="<?= $options[ "qb-name"]?>">
        </p>
    <?php }?>

<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!!

Comment: I added a </div> that was missing!